# Select OnChange

Tags: jquery, select, onchange, badge

This is a simple question.

How do I change the "badge's price from $10 to $20" with select onChange?

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">$10</span>

<select>
 <option>$10 Item</option>
 <option>$20 Item</option>
</select>
```

Please provide the HTML and jQuery.

P.S. I don't want to use an image for the badge's price. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: While adeneo as indulged you here, these types of questions ("Do my work for me") are generally discourages on Stack Overflow. In the future please show us what you've attempted to do to solve the problem before you posted the question.

Comment: Yes, I have tried and also did a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<span id="mybadge" class="badge badge-primary">$10</span>

<select id="myselect">
 <option value="$10">$10 Item</option>
 <option value="$20">$20 Item</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myselect').change(function(){
    $('#mybadge').text($(this).val());
});
```

Working jsFiddle ->> http://jsfiddle.net/sUBWd/5/