# Display HTML on the basis of dropdown menu selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu and on the basis of the item selected I want to display a small part of HTML page.

```
<select id='menuHandler'>
     <option value='abc'> abc</option>
     <option value='xyz'>xyz</option>
</select>
```

IF the selected value is "abc" then a popup button is displayed with the following code:

```
<button id='runForm' onClick=""> Run form </button>
<div id ="runFormPopup" style=" display:none;">
    <table   CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="5" class='border'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'>Run form Generation</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" class='border'>
                <span>Input Data</span><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" >Process log(s)<br>
                Summary data<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" >Thickness data<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" >Particle data
            </td>
            <td class='border'>
                <span>Steps(s)</span>
                <input type="checkbox" > 
                <input type="checkbox" > 
                <input type="checkbox" > 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>   Run form filename </td>
            <td><input type="text" ></td>
            <td><button class="editbtn">Generate</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

else if the value selected is "xyz" this should be displayed.

```
<form action="${ctx}/home/step50/generateReport" method="GET" id="form_generate">
    <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit" id="btnGenerate" class="small button active"  value="Generate"/>                                                    
</form>
```

how can I do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select OnChange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137744/select-onchange)

Answer (score 3):

Listen to the `change` event of the `#menuHandler` select element, and add the conditional logic there.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jux2apLw/)

```
$('#menuHandler').on('change', function () {
  if (this.value === "abc") {
    $('#runFormPopup, #runForm').show();
    $('#form_generate').hide();
  } else {
    $('#runFormPopup, #runForm').hide();
    $('#form_generate').show();
  }
});
```

..or a shorter version:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/spoqmsf7/)

```
$('#menuHandler').on('change', function () {
  var condition = this.value === "abc";

  $('#runFormPopup, #runForm').toggle(condition);
  $('#form_generate').toggle(!condition);
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect, you just _forgot_ to show/hide the button: `$('#runFormPopup, #runForm').toggle(condition);`

Comment: one small query: I already have abc selected but it doesnt show the table ??
so instead of select in the dropdown I have abc selected therefor I want to show the menu when the page first loads and it should change if the user selects xyz

Comment: @PSDebugger Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfcxnhu5/). You would just trigger a `change` event after the event listener using `$('#menuHandler').trigger('change')`. In doing so, the correct elements will be hidden/shown on load rather than the first time it is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
$('#menuHandler').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue === 'abc') { 
        $('#runFormPopup').show(); 
        $('#form_generate').hide();
    }
    else { 
        $('#runFormPopup').hide(); 
        $('#form_generate').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

From a high-level perspective:

- Create a listener on the button and listen for a click
- Dynamically get the value
- Either create the content for which you are looking, or insert content into a dynamically-created `<div>` (overlay, pop-up, etc.)

Following these steps, you should be OK.

Comment: Be careful; this came across the Low Quality Posts queue! In the future, keep chattiness out of answers; it's not constructive, and it detracts focus from an actual answer. I've expanded your hint into an answer; please edit your answer if you'd like to add additional information. Cheers!